# Python - search folder name in file path

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to identify a "episodeNumber" based on folder name in a file adress. the name containt the 2 letters "ep" followed by 3 numbers, from "001" to "999"

example path :

```
N://out/ep001/FX/maya/file4984.ma
```

i'm looking for a way to have a variable that result the episode number (ep001 in this example)

```
print(episodeNumber)
'ep001'
```

then i can put the "episodeNumber" in an other adress, like

```
newPath = "Y://work/" + episodeNumber + "/comp/"
print(newPath)
'Y://work/ep001/comp/'
```

How can I identify the episode number in a path to put it in an other one ?

I'm using python 2.7

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "identify"? Construct a [MCVE], please.

Comment: have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: if epXXX in fileAddressString

Comment: In my example, i need to have the « epxxx » folder name. XXX are numbers from 001 to 999. The rest of the adress is static. I need to identify this folder name to identify in what episode folder a file is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find regex powerful but less readable, especially if you haven't used it in a while, so here's a solution without it using other native modules.

```
import os
import fnmatch


def get_episode(path):
    # Split the path (should be OS independent).
    path_split = os.path.normpath(path).split(os.sep)

    # Find the episode using fnmatch.
    # This enforces your conventions that it must follow 3 numbers after 'ep'.
    episodes = fnmatch.filter(path_split, "ep[0-9][0-9][0-9]")
    if not episodes:
        raise RuntimeError, "Unable to detect episode in the supplied path."

    # In theory the path may yield multiple episodes from it, so just return the first one.
    return episodes[0]


episode = get_episode("N://out/ep001/FX/maya/file4984.ma")

# Use os.path.join to build your new path. 
new_path = os.path.join(os.path.normpath("Y://"), "work", episode, "comp")
```

This example produces this result:

> 'ep001' # episode
>
> 'Y:\work\ep001\comp' # new_path (I'm on Windows so I get double
>   backslashes)

It's better to use `os.path` methods to make it work cross-platform instead of using `+` to build your paths.

This has been tested on Python 2.7.11

Comment: I think your solution is better for this specific problem, you can also replace the "ep" part with "[eE][pP]" for case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 2):

```
from __future__ import print_function
# the above import is for python2 compatibility (question author request)
# it has to be at the top of the module
# you may need to install it with `pip install future`

import re

file_address = 'N://sessionY/ep001/out-montageFX/maya/'

# ok let's write a regex to find the part we want
# here (ep) part means that we want to capture `ep` to a `capture group`
# the (\d{3}) part means match the exactly 3 integers and capture them
# [\\/] matches backward or forward slashes (for windows support)
# more on regexes here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re
# on match objects here: 
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

regex = r'[\\/](ep)(\d{3})[\\/]'

# next we apply the expression with re.search
# (which means find the first matching occurrence)
# details here: 
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects

m = re.search(regex, file_address, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# the flags=re.IGNORECASE part - to match case-insensitivelly

if m:  # if a match has been found

    # we can get the folder_name `ep` part from the capture group 1
    # and the episode number from the capture group 2

    folder_name = m.group(1) + m.group(2)

    # as explained above the episode number is within group 1
    # and we also need to convert it to integer (if desired)
    # the group is guaranteed to have the match in it, because 
    # we are inside the above if statement.
    episode_number = int(m.group(2))

    # lets print the results:
    print('folder_name:', folder_name)
    print('episode_number:', episode_number)
else:
    # obviously no match
    print('no match')
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: If you're going to post a code-only answer, can you please at least post code that doesn't throw syntax errors?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, sorry my phone didn't let me use the right quotes ) updated

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, I elaborated the answer, here u go

Comment: hello bob, thank you but it doesnt work
seems to be for python 3, i'm on python 2.7

Comment: @WilliamEguienta, I edited it for python2-compatibility (just add the top line `from __future__ import print_function` (may need to install __future__ with `pip install future` see http://python-future.org/quickstart.html ) or you can just replace all print("...") with print "..."

Comment: @Bob thank you but sadly i cant install anything, as the script will be used on several computers and i don't have access to them
- print(...) works in python2.7 - i think it doesn't work because of regex = r'/ep(\d{3})/' - i always have print no match answer

Comment: @WilliamEguienta, maybe you need case-insensitivity and windows support? (windows paths use backward slashes), updated to match these requirements, no idea what else can be wrong unless you have mistakes in your question, it works in python2, I checked.

Comment: @Bob thank you, it works if i use something like `file_address = 'N://sessionY/ep001/out-montageFX/maya/'` but not if my adress is from 'filename' in `listdir` like `for filename in os.listdir(path):
` any idea why ?

Comment: @WilliamEguienta, it doesn't work with os.listdir because it returns not the full path, but directory names without slashes (e.g. 'ep001'). To match them you have to replace the regex with r'^(ep)(\d{3})$' (i.e. remove slashes from it and add ^ and $ - symbols matching the beginning and the end of the string, so it won't match something like 'xep001y'